# How do I re-execute a skipped section in Oracle Data Pump?

Tags: oracle, import, data-pump

I did a start_job=skip_current on a large import because I thought it was hanging on some bad data.  It turns out it was just a really large index so I'd like to re-run it but I don't want to do the entire import again. I know I can have it skip tables that are already there using the table_exists_action parameter, but does that apply to other objects, like indexes?  If not, is there any way to just import the items I skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract the SQL (sqlfile=xxxx) and create the index(es) by hand ?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing so I'm accepting this answer, although I think setting table_exists_action=skip would work. I know it works for tables, but I'm not sure about indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what index is missing, Datapump supports an "include=" parameter that should allow you to import just this one object.